# Is it possible to open an external URL without changing pages -- similar to those javascript image viewer popouts

Tags: javascript, image, viewer

I'd like to host some images on my website and let people post URL's to them. However, I don't want people to have to be redirected to my website to view them. Is there some way to setup my site so that no matter where the URL is posted, it will open up without changing pages? Similar looking to lightscribe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If people are simply posting links to your site like `<a href="http://example.com">`, there's nothing you can do on `example.com` to prevent them from leaving the referring page.

You could provide a piece of code that will create a lightbox-like effect and encourage your users to use it instead of the URL. Like YouTube, for example, which provides a chunk of HTML that creates an embedded player.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) type links. But you need a bit JS experience for this, though it sure can be done.